# how to get data from local google Auth?

Tags: authentication

I am facing a problem in findding a login data of user and user is logedin to my site using google auth platform and i want to get that login data and store data in my local storage and I am working on Angular 14
Kindly help if any one know the soluiton of this problem
Thanks

I had searched a lot but not find a convieniet solution

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me in this way.
According to the new documentation of Google (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview), you should follow next steps:

1. Create a google app in google cloud console platform and generate a client id.
2. Load the client library. Add this script "`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`" async defer>" between the `<head></head>` tags of your index.html file of Angular project.
3. Add this code on ngOnInit() function in the component that you would like to have "Sign in with Google button."

> ngOnInit() {
>
> ```
>   // @ts-ignore
>   google.accounts.id.initialize({
>     client_id: "YOUR GOOGLE CLIENT ID",
>     callback: this.handleCredentialResponse.bind(this),
>     auto_select: false,
>     cancel_on_tap_outside: true,
>
>   });
>   // @ts-ignore
>   google.accounts.id.renderButton(
>   // @ts-ignore
>   document.getElementById("google-button"),
>     { theme: "outline", size: "large", width: "100%" }
>   );
>   // @ts-ignore
>   google.accounts.id.prompt((notification: PromptMomentNotification) => {});
> }
> ```

> ```
> async handleCredentialResponse(response: any) {
>   // Here will be your response from Google.
>   console.log(response);
> }
> ```

4. Add div or button element to the html file of this component, with the same id that you mentioned into the initialization. ( "google-button" ):

> `<div class="" id="google-button"></div>.`

Let me know if you have any issues.